# Concatenate String encoded Buffer with a Buffer without creating another concatenating Buffer

Tags: node.js, buffer

I have a `Buffer` that must be the prefix of every string UTF-8 encoded `Buffer`,
The simple way to do it is:

```
const stringEncodedBuffer = Buffer.from( str ); //Buffer containing encoded UTF-8 String
const ConcatnetedBuffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe( prefixBuffer.byteLength + stringEncodedBuffer.byteLength);    //new created Buffer using allocUnsafe for preformance

//Copying Buffers to ConcatnetedBuffer

prefixBuffer.copy( ConcatnetedBuffer );
prefixBuffer.copy( stringEncodedBuffer , prefixBuffer.byteLength );
```

Assuming that: `prefixBuffer.byteLength < stringEncodedBuffer.byteLength`,
It is less efficient to copy like that, instead it's more efficient to do this:

```
const ConcatnetedBuffer = Buffer.from( '#'.repeat( prefixBuffer.byteLength ) + str );

//Copying Buffers to ConcatnetedBuffer

prefixBuffer.copy( ConcatnetedBuffer );
prefixBuffer.copy( stringEncodedBuffer , prefixBuffer.byteLength );
```

I also tried setting `ConcatnetedBuffer` size to `Buffer.byteLength(str) + prefixBuffer.byteLength`, and it appears to be less efficient also.

Buffer created using `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` and `Buffer.from(array)` both using `Buffer.poolSize` if possible, and it makes them more efficient.

Is there a better way of encoding `String` and preserving a number of `Bytes`?